# how to keep only numbers from a single column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, numbers, extract, datalist

I used following code to reconstruct my original dataframe (for the 1st dataset in a list) from output of lapply function (S.list) which gave me a single number for each of the datalist.

```
 data1$S <- S.list[1]
```

S.list was extracted from lapply funciton with which I applied a function to a list of 6 datasets and got a single number for each dataset in a list.
Then I wanted to reconstruct the original dataframe for all 6 datasets in the list. this is the example I reconstructed for the 1st dataset of the list and I saved the result in S column. But S column returns into something like this

```
       S 
c(`Julia` = 0.245133133918501)
c(`Julia` = 0.245133133918501)
c(`Julia` = 0.245133133918501)
c(`Julia` = 0.245133133918501)
...
```

So how can I delete others except from number (0.245133). I need only the number.

Comment: Please create a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to do it

```
data1=read.table(text="
      S
      'c(`Julia` = 0.245133133918501)'
      'c(`Julia` = 0.245133133918501)'
      'c(`Julia` = 0.245133133918501)'
      'c(`Julia` = 0.245133133918501)'
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

data1$S = as.numeric(sub("(.+= )([0-9\\.]+)(.+)", "\\2", data1$S, perl = T))

data1$S
# [1] 0.2451331 0.2451331 0.2451331 0.2451331
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! output is what I want but only 4 obs of 1 variable is extracted. My original data has 350 rows and 12 columns. Is it possible to keep all the rows and columns

Comment: ok. I just gave a different name when read.table instead of data1 then It works well. Thank you so much!